# Regarding the proof of Cor. 4.2 of Stein-Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

This corollary shows that for a holomorphic function $f$, under certain conditions
$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta$$

In the proof of this result, [here on Google Books](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=0ECHh9tjPUAC&lpg=PP1&dq=cauchy%20integral%20formula%20proof%20stein%20shakarchi&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false), in going from eq. (9) to the last displayed equation a limit and an integral is exchanged.

What is the justification for this exchange?

The integral here is the Riemann integral along a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I justify it. I hope it helps you.

(using the same notation as in the book)
We are finding the limit of the integral in (9) when $ h\rightarrow 0 $.
By Heine definition of limit, consider an arbitrary secuence $ h_k\rightarrow 0 $, to jutify the exchange is enough to show that $ g_k(\zeta) $ converges, uniformly in $ C $, to the integrand in your equation. Where $ g_k(\zeta) $ is the integrand in (9) substituting $ h $ for $ h_k $.

Is easy to prove the uniform convergence in $ C $ of $ A_k $ to $ B $ (where $ A_k $ is a function of $ \zeta $ as in the book, but substituting $ h $ for $ h_k $) . And use that result to prove (by induction) the uniform convergence of $ {A_k}^n $ to $ B^n $ for all natural $ n $. With that you get the uniform convergence of $ g_k $.